# IBM Cloud - Cloud Foundry App Go deploying failed

Tags: go, ibm-cloud

I am trying to start a Go Cloud Foundry App on IBM Cloud but the deploying is not working. The error states

```
  Unable to determine Go version to install: no match found for 1.8.3 in 
  1.6.3 1.6.4 1.7.5 1.7.6 1.8.6 1.8.7 1.9.3 1.9.4 1.10]
```

Is this something I can fix or is this something IBM Cloud needs to fix? I work at IBM so any IBM employee can contact me through our internal communication systems preferable slack.

The full build error is

```
Getting app info...
Updating app with these attributes...
  name:                go-logs
  path:                /home/pipeline/452c2d32-763b-4da7-ba9a-c6447b37016c
  disk quota:          1G
  health check type:   port
  instances:           1
  memory:              128M
  stack:               cflinuxfs2
  routes:
    go-logs.eu-de.mybluemix.net

Updating app [36;1mgo-logs[0m...
Mapping routes...
Comparing local files to remote cache...
Packaging files to upload...
Uploading files...

 0 B / 27.80 KiB    0.00%
 27.80 KiB / 27.80 KiB  100.00%
 27.80 KiB / 27.80 KiB  100.00%
 27.80 KiB / 27.80 KiB  100.00%
 27.80 KiB / 27.80 KiB  100.00%
 27.80 KiB / 27.80 KiB  100.00%
 27.80 KiB / 27.80 KiB  100.00% 1s

Waiting for API to complete processing files...

Staging app and tracing logs...
   Downloading python_buildpack...
   Downloading liberty-for-java_v3_26-20181023-1545...
   Downloading sdk-for-nodejs_v3_25-20181219-1036...
   Downloading swift_buildpack_v2_0_15-20180920-0051...
   Downloading liberty-for-java...
   Downloaded sdk-for-nodejs_v3_25-20181219-1036
   Downloading sdk-for-nodejs...
   Downloaded liberty-for-java_v3_26-20181023-1545
   Downloading dotnet-core...
   Downloaded swift_buildpack_v2_0_15-20180920-0051
   Downloading swift_buildpack...
   Downloaded python_buildpack
   Downloading staticfile_buildpack...
   Downloaded liberty-for-java
   Downloading java_buildpack...
   Downloaded swift_buildpack
   Downloading ruby_buildpack...
   Downloaded sdk-for-nodejs
   Downloading nodejs_buildpack...
   Downloaded dotnet-core
   Downloading go_buildpack...
   Downloaded staticfile_buildpack
   Downloading liberty-for-java_v3_27-20181130-1702...
   Downloaded java_buildpack
   Downloading swift_buildpack_v2_0_16-20181214-0434...
   Downloaded ruby_buildpack
   Downloading php_buildpack...
   Downloaded nodejs_buildpack
   Downloading xpages_buildpack...
   Downloaded go_buildpack
   Downloading sdk-for-nodejs_v3_24-20181128-1339...
   Downloaded liberty-for-java_v3_27-20181130-1702
   Downloading binary_buildpack...
   Downloaded swift_buildpack_v2_0_16-20181214-0434
   Downloading dotnet-core_v2_0-20180918-1356...
   Downloaded sdk-for-nodejs_v3_24-20181128-1339
   Downloading dotnet-core_v2_1-20181205-1536...
   Downloaded xpages_buildpack
   Downloaded binary_buildpack
   Downloaded php_buildpack
   Downloaded dotnet-core_v2_0-20180918-1356
   Downloaded dotnet-core_v2_1-20181205-1536
   Cell 49d42072-0d96-446e-ae6f-b172ba8b41d3 creating container for instance f786b6b1-1abc-445b-a7fe-6bdc8c8adbcc
   Cell 49d42072-0d96-446e-ae6f-b172ba8b41d3 successfully created container for instance f786b6b1-1abc-445b-a7fe-6bdc8c8adbcc
   Downloading app package...
   Downloaded app package (27.5K)
   -----> Go Buildpack version 1.8.20
   -----> Checking Godeps/Godeps.json file
   -----> Installing godep v80
          Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/godep/godep-v80-linux-x64-3b019ddc.tgz]
   -----> Installing glide v0.13.1
          Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/glide/glide-v0.13.1-linux-x64-4959fbf0.tgz]
   -----> Installing dep v0.4.1
          Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/dep/dep-v0.4.1-linux-x64-c678d9fc.tgz]
          [31;1m**ERROR**[0m Unable to determine Go version to install: no match found for 1.8.3 in [1.6.3 1.6.4 1.7.5 1.7.6 1.8.6 1.8.7 1.9.3 1.9.4 1.10]
   [31mFailed to compile droplet: Failed to run all supply scripts: exit status 16[0m
   Exit status 223
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
[31;1mFAILED[0m

Finished: FAILED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the Go version you are using in your application is not a supported Cloud Foundry Go buildpack version on IBM Cloud. The same is mentioned in the build error as well. As per the documentation [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/go/index.html#go_runtime),

> The following Go versions are available in the Go buildpack currently
>   installed in IBM Cloud:
>
> 1.6.3
>   1.6.4
>   1.7.5
>   1.7.6
>   1.8.6
>   1.8.7
>   1.9.3
>   1.9.4
>   1.10

If your app requires a Go version that is not listed, you can use the external [Go buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-buildpack.git) to deploy the application.

To check the latest supported buildpacks, you can always run this command

```
ibmcloud cf buildpacks
```